# iterating through columns in a for loop in R by name

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a dataframe with some columns that are numeric and some that aren't, and i'm trying to write a for loop that will extract some stats from the numeric columns.

i can't figure out how to get the loop to recognize the variable as a column name.

this is the gist of what i have:

```
for(c in names(Data)) {
    if(class(Data$c)=='numeric') {
            sd(Data$c)
    }
}
```

... but class(Data$c) returns 'character' every time.

i realize i can just do this with sapply but this is bugging me!!!

Comment: use `Data[[c]]`, also, there is `is.numeric`, so you can use `if(is.numeric(Data[[c]])`  You can do it in `lapply/sapply` i.e. `lapply(Data, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sd(x))`

Comment: just do `rapply(Data,sd,"numeric")`

Answer (score 5):

The issue could be the use of `$` instead of `[[`.  By using `$`, it checks for the columns that matches `c` instead of getting the value inside the `c` i.e. the actual column names.  So, we need to use `[[`   Also, for storing purpose

```
Data <- iris
out <- c() 
for(c in names(Data)) {
if(class(Data[[c]])=='numeric') {
        out <- c(out, sd(Data[[c]]))
  }
}
```

In addition, the function `is.numeric` checks whether it is numeric or not

```
out <- c()
for(c in names(Data)) {
if(is.numeric(Data[[c]])) {
      out <- c(out, sd(Data[[c]]))
  }
}
```

---

Using `lapply/sapply`, loop through the columns of the dataset and `if` it is `numeric`, then get the `sd` of the column

```
lapply(Data, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sd(x))
```

Comment: don't you think `rapply(Data,sd,"numeric")` would be a better idea?

Comment: @Onyambu  It is a recursive version with `classes` argument.  I am not sure whether it is better or not (with regards to performance for a non-nested dataset), but it is interesting

Comment: Well whenever I have to perform a task on a specified class i do think of `rapply` so i guess it will work here too

Comment: @Onyambu  It works here, but I am not sure about the performance because of the additional checks

Comment: Will look into that

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a column named `c` which contains characters. `Data$c` identifies the column in `Data` named `c`. If you want the `c` as in the current value of `names()` from your loop, that is `Data[[c]]`.

Personally I'd use `dplyr::summarise_if()`:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

data.frame's column should be 1 class: i.e. all `character` or all `numeric`
with `c(1,2,3,"4")` column, forced casting will occurs and you will get `character` column...

so, you need `numeric cast-able` checking, not `numeric checking`

```
key <- LETTERS[1:10]
value <- c(1:9,"10")
df <- data.frame(key, value, key, value, value, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

numeric.col <- which(!is.na(sapply(df, as.numeric)[1,]))
sapply(df[,numeric.col], sd)
```

[image]